# I made per prefix command and a help command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

**on my help command there is prefix of not but i want to put it asper server prefix there like if someone change the prefix of my bot in their server on help command it should come prefix for their server i need help in that if its possible**

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");
    const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
    const { stripIndents } = require("common-tags");
    const { embedcolor } = require("../../configs/config.json");
    const { default_prefix } = require("../../configs/config.json")
    const config = require('../../configs/config.json');

    module.exports = {
        config: {
            name: "help",
            aliases: ["h"],
            usage: "[command name] (optional)",
            category: "info",
            description: "",
            accessableby: "everyone"
        },
        run: async (client, message, args) => {

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor(embedcolor)
                .setAuthor(`${message.guild.me.displayName}`, message.guild.iconURL())
                .setThumbnail(client.user.displayAvatarURL())

            if (!args[0]) {

                embed.setDescription(`Soune's Prefix Is \`${default_prefix}\``)
                embed.setFooter(`${message.guild.me.displayName} | Total Commands - ${client.commands.size - 1} Loaded`, client.user.displayAvatarURL());
                embed.addField(`util [7] - `, '`dm`, `fullembed`, `help`, `poll`, `say`, `snipe`, `prefix`')
                embed.addField(`Fun [5] - `, '`cute`,`cat`, `dog`, `meme`, `ping`,')
                embed.addField(`Mod [13] - `, '`ban`, `clear`, `give-roles`, `kick`, `mute`, `nuke`, `slowmode`, `unmute`, `warn`, `lock`, `remove-roles`, `unban`, `unlock`')
                embed.addField(`info [6] - `, '`bot-info`, `server-info`, `total-bans`, `user-info`, `profile`, `uptime`')
                embed.addField(`giveaway [4] - `, '`giveaway`, `reroll`, `edit`, `end`')
                   
           
                embed.setFooter(`Antra My Owner`)
              
                embed.setTimestamp()

                return message.channel.send(embed)
            } else {
                let command = client.commands.get(client.aliases.get(args[0].toLowerCase()) || args[0].toLowerCase())
                if (!command) return message.channel.send(embed.setTitle("**Invalid Command!**").setDescription(`**Do \`${default_prefix}help\` For the List Of the Commands!**`))
                command = command.config

                embed.setDescription(stripIndents`**Prefix Is \`${default_prefix}\`**\n
                ** Command -** ${command.name.slice(0, 1).toUpperCase() + command.name.slice(1)}\n
                ** Description -** ${command.description || "No Description provided."}\n
                ** Usage -** ${command.usage ? `\`${default_prefix}${command.name} ${command.usage}\`` : "No Usage"}\n
                ** Needed Permissions -** ${command.accessableby || "everyone can use this command!"}\n
                ** Aliases -** ${command.aliases ? command.aliases.join(", ") : "None."}`)
                embed.setFooter(message.guild.name, message.guild.iconURL())

                return message.channel.send(embed)
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: You'll need to set up a database to keep track of prefixes

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I recommend using [NeDB](https://npmjs.com/package/nedb) for your database. [Here's a useful tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVYa20DCUv0) Happy coding!

Comment: Thx so much if I cant figure out I will see a yt tutorial and idk how to keep track of prefixes

Comment: is it hard with mongodb?